# Installing Ubuntu and removing Windows

Tags: ubuntu

I installed just the Ubuntu server without desktop on to my laptop to use as a simple file server. I already had windows 7 on the laptop. When I came to the partitioning options on installation from CD I chose the 'use entire disk' option and also did the grub install because I wanted to remove Windows 7 completely. But I'm now wondering if these options did actually remove Windows 7 or if I have to do something more. I want to remove it completely to free up as much space on my hard drive as possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for questions about programming. Your question may be better served at AskUbuntu.com, the Stackexchange site for Ubuntu Linux. Please check their quality standards and search before asking, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you told the Ubuntu installer to use the entire disk, it will use the entire disk. I recently found this out when even a tiny recovery partition was removed during the process.

You can check the size of your partitions with `df -h`. For my 256GB SSD drive this returns:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       231G   13G  207G   6% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,9G  1,6M  1,9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           386M  1,2M  385M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,9G  1,1M  1,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
```

The total size is close to 256GB (GB vs GiB). Also, there are no fat or ntfs filesystems present, so no Windows partitions.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much, how much space does just the Ubuntu server take up or does that depend on the packages used?

Comment: As you said, that depend on the installed packages. For a fresh server I think it is about 1 or 2 GB, probably closer to 1 GB.